# How can I disable automatic opening/saving of file downloads

Tags: php, .htaccess

If I have a `mp3` or `wav` file on a page... when i visit that page in Internet Explorer it starts downloading that `mp3` or `wav` or `mov` file automatically instead of playing that file. How can i prevent that either with `.htaccess` or php or html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a streaming server: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_streaming_media_systems